# How can I add auto-increment number at the end of the each line in my text document via Vim

Tags: vim

How can I add auto-increment number at the end of the each line in my text document via Vim?

Suppose that I have the following file:

```
some_text
other_text
another_text
```

Expected output:

```
some_text 1
other_text 2
another_text 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use expression in substitution:

```
:%s/$/\=' '.line('.')/
```

---

<sub>Type `:help :s\=` in vim to learn more.</sub>

Comment: `' '.line('.')` (concate white-space and line-num) is a vim expression. The syntax is like `perl`.

Comment: `line('.')` is a vim function called with a argument `'.'`(dot) which stands for the current line.